# Refactoring C# switch to remove explicit calls to methods using Reflection and DI

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, refactoring

so i have been tasked with refactoring some code and have so far been unable to get to a working solution. The goal of the refactoring is to remove the explicit call to the subclasses by using reflection and dependency injection. The results should not change but the code should allow for new subclasses to be added without the need to rewrite any part of the code.

So far my idea was to first using Reflection API to get all the subclasses of the main abstract Instruction class, then get the execute method paramaters for each and here is where i am stuck, i have no idea how to use Dependancy injection to replace the switch statement.

Here is the relevant code:
**Translator.cs**

```
switch (opcode)
{
    case "add":
        ins = new AddInstruction(label, r, s1, s2);
        break;
    case "sub":
        ins = new SubtractInstruction(label, r, s1, s2);
        break;
    case "mul":
        ins = new MultiplyInstruction(label, r, s1, s2);
        break;
    case "div":
        ins = new DivisionInstruction(label, r, s1, s2);
        break;
    case "out":
        ins = new PrintInstruction(label, s1);
        break;
    case "lin":
        ins = new StoreInstruction(label, r, s1);
        break;
    case "bnz":
        ins = new SwitchInstruction(label, s1, l2);
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

**Instruction.cs**

```
public abstract class Instruction
{
    private string label;
    private string opcode;

    protected Instruction(string label, string opcode)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.opcode = opcode;
    }

    public override string ToString() => label + ": " + opcode;

    // Execute this instruction on machine m. 
    public abstract void Execute(Machine m);
}
```

**AddInstruction.cs   All other instructions have similar layouts**

```
public class AddInstruction : Instruction
{
    private int reg, s1, s2;

    public AddInstruction(string lab, int reg, int s1, int s2) : base(lab, "Add")
    {
        this.reg = reg;
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    public override void Execute(Machine m) =>
        m.Registers[reg] = m.Registers[s1] + m.Registers[s2];

    public override string ToString() =>
        base.ToString() + " r[" + reg + "] r[" + s1 + "] r[" + s2 + "]";
}
```

How would one go about making it so that the program can take future implementations of the Instruction class without using a length switch statement?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just use polymorphism? Based on your description and code, I don't see the need to use reflection. Do you need to call other methods from the subclasses that are not overriding the base class?

Comment: @insane_developer I forgot to mention that due to spec i can't use any framework and must implement this myself. The base idea is that new instructions can be added and the code will just run without any changes. The spec itself specifies that Reflection must be used to achieve this. I do know that this is uncoventional as normally you would just use Autofac or others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have other options instead of Reflection for gathering all the subclasses.  Most DI frameworks will allow you inject all implementations of a abstract type or interface as an array of instances.  Some prudent searching online should give you results for  your particular DI framework.

You also have options for the switch statement.  One common pattern for this is the chain of command pattern. An example of that is here: https://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern

This would allow you to add new sub-classes without having to change the code executing the instructions.  It's not as efficient as the switch statement, but it's got the flexibility you're after.

A very simplistic example of that using your classes might look like this:

```
public abstract class Instruction
{
    string label;
    string opcode;

    protected Instruction(string label, string opcode)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.opcode = opcode;
    }

    public Instruction Next { get; set; }

    public void Execute(string op, Machine m)
    {
        if (this.opcode == op)
        {
            this.OnExecute(m);
            return;
        }

        if (null != this.Next)
        {
            this.Next.Execute(op, m);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown operation");
    }

    // Execute this instruction on machine m. 
    protected abstract void OnExecute(Machine m);
}

public class AddInstruction : Instruction
{
    private int reg, s1, s2;

    public AddInstruction(string lab, int reg, int s1, int s2) : 
        base(lab, "Add")
    {
        this.reg = reg;
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    protected override void OnExecute(Machine m)
    {
        m.Registers[reg] = m.Registers[s1] + m.Registers[s2];
    }
}

public class MultiplyInstruction : Instruction
{
    private int reg, s1, s2;

    public MultiplyInstruction(string lab, int reg, int s1, int s2) :
        base(lab, "Mul")
    {
        this.reg = reg;
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    protected override void OnExecute(Machine m)
    {
        m.Registers[reg] = m.Registers[s1] * m.Registers[s2];
    }
}
```

You would then build the chain and execute the instructions like so:

```
        Instruction[] subclasses = new Instruction[] { new AddInstruction("Add", 1, 2, 3), new MultiplyInstruction("Multiply", 2, 3, 4) };

        Instruction previous = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < subclasses.Length; ++i)
        {
            var current = subclasses[i];

            if (null != previous)
                previous.Next = current;

            previous = current;
        }

        var head = subclasses[0];
        var machine = new Machine();

        foreach (var op in "Mul,Add,Mul,Add".Split(','))
        {
            head.Execute(op, machine);
        }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that due to spec i can't use any framework and must implement this myself. The base idea is that new instructions can be added and the code will just run without any changes. The spec itself specifies that Reflection must be used to achieve this. I do know that this is uncoventional as normally you would just use Autofac or others.

Comment: @FabioM The chain of command pattern would work still, you'll just use reflection to find all the various implementations of it instead of DI.  There are likely other patterns that would be useful but this is a pretty simple one to implement and would solve the problem.